# How to link Note Velocity to Volume in Live or FL Studio?

Tags: midi, ableton-live

I have raw midi data generated through a script (in form of note on, note off , velocities etc). I am sending this data to a DAW ( FL Studio and Ableton Live) using LoopMIDI. How do I control say volume of a sound being played in FL Studio or Ableton Live using the value of Note Velocity?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, so it'll probably be closed. In your DAW, assign velocity to volume. A lot of times you'll find that it's already mapped that way.

Comment: My guess is that you want to control the volume of a playing audio file with the notes and velocities of the incoming notes in a different midi track, is that correct? In Ableton Live you could do this with Max for Live, making this a programming question :)